# How to import data from growing pivot table excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table which I'm using to import values in another worksheet. So, there's are cells like `2017-14, 2017-13` etc.

The data in the pivot table keeps on growing each week, like this week `column O` has `2017-14` data, `column P` has `2017-15` data, but next week there will also be a `column Q` which will have `2017-16` data, and I want to import data from this pivot table into my worksheet every week for the last 3 weeks worth of data ( so, this week for 2017-15, 2017-14, 2017-13, but next week for 2017-16, 2017-15, 2017-14 and so on) How do I refer this in my worksheet from the pivot table such that I don't have to manually do it each week?

Answer (score 0):

For "how do I extract this 14, because I want it to display as WK14 when the value is 2017-14" please try:

```
="WK"&RIGHT(Pivot_Table!O5,2)
```